# receiving stdin with a call to open a regular file in linux

Tags: linux, file, system-calls, descriptor

I have a program which opens a static file with sys_open() and wants to receive a file descriptor equals to zero (=stdin). I have the ability to write to the file, remove it or modify it, so I tried to create a symbolic link to /dev/stdin from the static file name. It opens stdin, but returns with the lowest available fd (not equal to zero). How can I cause the syscall to return zero, without hooking the syscall or modifying the program itself? it that even possible?

(It's part of a challenge, not a real case scenario)

Thank you as always

Comment: What is `sys_open()`?

Comment: @mosvy it's a linux system call. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: That's `open`, not `sys_open`. And nowadays, the `open` library function is actually implemented with the `openat` system call on Linux. Strace any program on any recent system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Posix guarantees](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14) that the lowest available FD will be returned. Therefore you can just invoke the program with stdin closed:

```
./myprogram 0>&-
```

Comment: Not only linux, and not only in practice. [File Descriptor Allocation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_14)